# Evaluate : $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin^3(x)\cdot \sin(x+a)}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate: $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin^3x\cdot \sin(x+a)}}dx$$

I've tried to integrate this thing but this is looking complex integration so someone help me to integrate

Comment: $$\sqrt{sin(x)^3\sin(x+a)}=\sin(x)\sqrt{\sin(x)\sin(x+a)}$$

Comment: I don't think it would help. I tried this already

Comment: Are you sure that this is the exact problem as written? This seems pretty monstrous.

Comment: Yes I'm sure and yes it's pretty monstrous too

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2FSqrt%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5E3+Sin%5Bx%2Ba%5D%5D,x%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No complex integration needed for evaluation of this integral.

You have $\sin^3 x\sin(x+a)=\sin^4x(\cos a+\sin a\cot x)$.

Substitute $\cos a+\sin a\cot x=t^2$

Then $$I=\int\frac{\csc^2 x}{\sqrt{\cos a+\sin a\cot x}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{-2t/\sin a}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Now write the final answer in terms of the original variable.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Write

$$\sin^3 x \sin(x+a) = \sin^4x(\cos a + \cot x \sin a)$$ 
then put $t=  \cos a +\ cotx \sin a$. Then 
$$dt =-\sin a \csc^2x dx$$

Therefore the integral transforms to $-\csc a\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$

Comment: And then what should I do?

Comment: So if you think that question is good one then please upvote the question because it is in negative rated condition so any professional will not try to solve this.

Comment: @tired see the edited answer. The hint was not useless.

Comment: @SagarMishra check the edit.